# Make a shortcut for Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net

I have to type Console.WriteLine() many times in my code.
Is it possible to create a shortcut for Console.WriteLine so that I can use it like...

```
CW=Console.WriteLine();
// After that, I can use this CW for my Console.WriteLine() like
CW("Print Something");
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Visual Studio already has a default code snippet for this. Just type `cw` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>. Note that if you're considering using a method, it may lack some features like the automatic string.Format and other overloaded parameters.

Comment: Also, using a shortcut, you have to be very careful of things like a mismatch between format items and items in an argument list, which the compiler warns about if you explicitly call `Console.WriteLine`.  
  I just lost quite some time because my `ReportTermination` method traced and wrote to console error information.  I used a constant format string (message) in the method, so a property I was passing as an argument to the format string was being interpreted as the format string, leaving the argument list one item short, raising another, mystery, exception.

Comment: My apologies. The compiler doesn't generate a warning; it's ReSharper that warns be. Any standard call to `Console.WriteLine` with a mismatched argument list will raise an exception. Maybe a shortcut that checks for this is worth it.

Comment: in my copy of visual studio cw<tab><tab> is what works for me. That is, I need to press tab twice after the shortcut.

Comment: You can find the "cw" shortcut under Tools > Code Snippets Manager > Language:CSharp > Folder:Visual C# .
The full definition is in the .snippet XML file, eg. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\cw.snippet". The code that gets inserted is in the "Code" element. 
This file should give you enough pointers to create your own.

Comment: press tab twice

Comment: Same for [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html#Live_cw_CSHARP) and [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html#Live_cw_CSHARP) - `cw<tab>`.

Answer (score 39):

If you are on .NET 3.5 or newer:

```
Action<string> cw = Console.WriteLine;

cw("Print Something");
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Is it possible to add some description to this shortcut which would be displayed upon mouse hover?

Comment: +1 for cleverness, and being exactly the sort of thing the asker wanted.  Be careful about member access modifiers, though: there's the possibility for unsafe/unscrupulous/unclear programming when one starts going down this road.

Comment: +1: Was going to be my second choice answer, after the accepted one. I like this, but it does add risk.

Answer (score 13):

You could no doubt create a [Visual Studio snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) for it (although actually there's one already for `cw`, apparently - try it!).

I would personally suggest that you *don't* use a shortcut *within the code* - it's likely to be clearer to anyone *reading* it if it still says `Console.WriteLine`.

Depending on what this is for, it *may* make sense to write a helper method called, say, `Log` - that has a reasonable *meaning*, whereas `CW` doesn't.

(If this *is* for logging, consider using something more powerful such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), too.)

Answer (score 13):

[C# 6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6/) adds the `using static` feature:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program {
  void Main(string[] args) {
     WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", "world");
  }
}
```

IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015 understands this new syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that but only for one function and not all static functions in `Console`?

Answer (score 5):

If you want it global, you could write an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static void ConLog(this string msg)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(msg);
   }
}
```

Now wherever you are, you can call `"My Message".ConLog();` on any string in your application and write it to the console.

Comment: that would not work with the Console.Writline's intelli-sense

Answer (score 3):

To piggyback on [Michael Stum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91/michael-stum)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613693), we could also make `object` as the type parameter to `Action` delegate like so:

```
Action<object> cw = x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

I usually do that on my C# Interactive window to quickly print out objects that I'm working with.

For example:

```
> var grid = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='ReactVirtualized__Grid__innerScrollContainer']//div"));
> cw(grid);
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]
>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void CW(string str)
{
     Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have **ReSharper** you can type ***out*** and *Enter* and the row

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("");
```

will be written.

In case you want to output a variable there is another *live template*: ***outv***.

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("time = {0}", time);
```

Here *time* is a variable which you could select after typing *outv*.

Answer (score 2):

If you write this at the top of the page:

```cs
using j = System.Console;
```

then at any time, you can use

```cs
j.WriteLine("Anything you want to write");
```

And that's all.

By the way, you can use anything instead of the "j".

Answer (score 1):

Write a method which returns void and call it for `Console.WriteLine()`.

```
void Log(string msg)
{
   Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a static method to wrap the call:

```
static class C
{
    static void W(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

then:

```
C.W("Print Something");
```

I would be inclined to use the "inline method" refactoring before checking in any code that calls this method.  As Jon Skeet notes, it's less confusing simply to use Console.WriteLine directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
// For formatting string and parameters define a function
// The shortcut function wl, kind of write line
public void wl( string format, params object[] parms){
    Console.WriteLine(format, parms);
}

// Just for strings we can use Action delegate
Action<string> ws = Console.WriteLine;

// examples:
ws("String with no formatting parameters");

wl("String without formatting parameters");
wl("String with {0} parameters {1}", 2, "included");
wl("several parameters {0} {1} {2} repeated {0}", 1234, 5678, 6543);
```

or using extension method: formatString.wl(arguments...)

```
public static class ConsoleWriteExtensions
{
    public static void wl(this string format, params object[] parms){
        Console.WriteLine(format, parms);
    }
}

"{0} -> {1}".wl("Mili",123.45); // prints Mili -> 123.45
```

Answer (score 0):

This shortcut will avoid exceptions being thrown when you use a composite formatting overload like `Console.WriteLine(String, Object[])` and the number of format items in `format` and the number of items in the argument list, `args`, differ:

```
public bool WriteToConsole(string format, params object[] args)
{           
    var succeeded = false;
    var argRegex = new Regex(@"\{\d+\}");
    if ((args != null) && (argRegex.Matches(format).Count == args.Length))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(format, args);
        succeeded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(format);
    }
    return succeeded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites also...
Coming from BASIC and Python... I missed Print() very often...
I also use Print() extensively in JS/ES for console.log/other-consoles often...

So declare it as a function:

```
public static void Print( object x ){ Console.WriteLine( x ); }
```

- you can compose strings at your will as the function parameter like:

> ```
>  Print( "Hi\n\n" + x.toString() + "\n\nBye!!!" );
> ```

- or interpolate vars at will

> ```
> Print( $"{x} ~ {y} ~ {z}" );
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a function;

```
    static void print(string str)
    {
     Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

and call it anywhere...
(you can make it public if you want to.)

Comment: This is more or less just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613704).